# How to disable Winamp agent in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, winamp

I remember the days when I could right click on the Winamp icon in the Windows taskbar, and select "Disable Winamp Agent", and it would actually disable and not appear again.  This no longer seems to work on Windows 7 (or maybe Windows in general).  Every time I restart my PC, it appears in the taskbar again.

I like having my icons displaying in the taskbar.  Which is why I have "Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar" checked off.

I have Winamp v5.571 installed on Windows 7 Ultimate.

How do I properly turn off the Winamp agent from appearing in the Windows taskbar?  Right-click to disable doesn't work!

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the startup list? So that it's not launched with Windows itself?

Comment: @Ivo My Startup folder is empty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can disable it from Winamp Preferences window. The related settings are located under General Preferences -> File Types -> Winamp Agent box.

[image]

Comment: This is it!  And it solves another problem I was having with Winamp always assigning itself back to file associations I assigned to VLC media player.  Wish I could give double vote up on this answer!

Comment: So you killed two birds with one stone. Nice to help you.

Comment: Yes haha.  Winamp has just gotten more annoying and controlling over the years.  I miss it when it was more basic and slimmed down.  Thank you.

Comment: Then you may be interested in the old versions of Winamp: http://www.oldversion.com/Winamp.html

Comment: I was pulled away from Winamp when I discovered MediaMonkey. I like it so much I have paid for the Gold version twice now (once for version 3, once for version 4). If you are growing dissatisfied w/ Winamp, it might be worth a look. FWIW, free version is very good too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Click `start`, then `run`, then type `msconfig`.

Choose the startup tab, remove the tick from `Winamp` if it is enabled. Exit without restarting the computer.

Comment: A restart will stop winamp agent